# Create alias (desktop shortcut) of an application installed by Macports

Tags: macos, macports, alias, dia

I just installed Dia using macports.

Now, I need to place the shortcut in the Apps folder and also make the executable available in the Spotlight search.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacPorts installs it's applications by default in `/opt/local`. `dia` installs to `/opt/local/bin/dia`. Since the program is started from the command line and runs in X11, I suggest making an AppleScript program (or use [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus)) to do this for you. You can then save this program in the Applications folder so it can be found using Spotlight.

Sample AppleScript:

```
do shell script "/opt/local/bin/dia &"
```

Alternatively, a standalone application has been made by [dia-installer.de](http://dia-installer.de/) that you can copy right into your Applications folder.